# Python: creating separate columns for group labels and individual units when both are in the same column of the original data

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, grouping, multi-level

I am new to Python and I suspect this question might have been asked before, but I really could not find any relevant threads. Hence, the question.

I intend to create a data frame containing separate columns for "group labels" and "individual units," but the original raw data were structured like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('df.txt',  names = 'data')
```

which reads

```
        data
0 group1
1 unit_a
2 unit_b
3 group2
4 unit_c
5 unit_d
6 unit_e
7 group3
8 unit_f
9 unit_g
...
```

but I want to create a data frame like this

```
       Group   Unit
    0 group1 unit_a
    1 group1 unit_b
    2 group2 unit_c
    3 group2 unit_d
    4 group2 unit_e
    5 group3 unit_f
    6 group3 unit_g
    ...
```

That is, in the original data, units are listed under their respective group labels and they are all listed in the same column, while each group may contain different number of units. So I have a hard time slicing data using intervals or other methods. How can I sort or slice the original data into my desired two-column data frame-type output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these actually strings called `group1` and `unit_a` or are you using placeholders for some actual data here?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! They are strings (group names, individual names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rudimentary approach would be to just assign a new column with the masked values using `str.contains`, filter the rows where the columns matched (e.g. `group1, group1`), and then reset the index.

```
df = (df.assign(group=df[df.data.str.contains('group')])
        .ffill()
        .query('data != group')
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename(columns={'data':'unit'}))
```

I can't help but feel there is an easier way to go about this though.

**Demo**

```
>>>> (df.assign(group=df[df.data.str.contains('group')])
        .ffill()
        .query('data != group')
        .reset_index(drop=True))  
        .rename(columns={'data':'unit'}))

     unit   group
0  unit_a  group1
1  unit_b  group1
2  unit_c  group2
3  unit_d  group2
4  unit_e  group2
5  unit_f  group3
6  unit_g  group3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I add square brackets to subset the original data frame that gives several unique group names.
mask = df[df['data'].str.contains("group")]
but for the second step beginning with df[mask], since mask and df are data frame of different length, the proposed method will not work. I will continue to work on the code you provided.
I saw in another forum that recommends using partial string matches, but that's currently beyond me.
Update: Sorry I didn't see your updated code. I will try implementing that.

Comment: I am stuck in .query('data != group')  
Python returns an error message, something with the definition of "data," which was missing. Is the "data" in .query('data != group')  a data frame equivalent to df['a'] or df? 
Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisT. It is the column in your sample DataFrame labelled `data`.

Comment: It works! Nothing's wrong with the code, to be sure. My slow grasping with the string issue in "DataFrame.query()" is to be blamed. That said, your code (and this thread) improve my understanding of this issue.
Thank you!
I will post my revised code later.